# How can I make a ball of light in openGL?

Tags: java, c++, opengl, lighting

I'm trying to make a orb of light (Like a sun) but I can't seem to make it visible at all. I'll give you some snipets of code I have. It's in Java LWJGL, so it might look a little different.

```
private float lightAmbient[] = { 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f };  // Ambient Light Values ( NEW )
    private float lightDiffuse[] = { 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f };      // Diffuse Light Values ( NEW )
    private float lightPosition[] = { 0.0f, 0.0f, -5.0f, 1.0f }; // Light Position ( NEW )
    float lightSpecular[] = { 0f, 0f, 0.5f, 1.0f };  // highlight
```

and

```
ByteBuffer temp = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(16);
        temp.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        GL11.glLight(GL11.GL_LIGHT1, GL11.GL_AMBIENT, (FloatBuffer)temp.asFloatBuffer().put(lightAmbient).flip());              // Setup The Ambient Light
        GL11.glLight(GL11.GL_LIGHT1, GL11.GL_DIFFUSE, (FloatBuffer)temp.asFloatBuffer().put(lightDiffuse).flip());              // Setup The Diffuse Light
        GL11.glLight(GL11.GL_LIGHT1, GL11.GL_POSITION,(FloatBuffer)temp.asFloatBuffer().put(lightPosition).flip());         // Position The Light
        GL11.glLight(GL11.GL_LIGHT1, GL11.GL_SPECULAR,(FloatBuffer)temp.asFloatBuffer().put(lightSpecular).flip());         // Position The Light

        GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_LIGHT1);
```

What else do I have to do to make the light visible?

Answer (score 7):

Lights are never visible.

However, their affects on the **materials** of other objects are. It's therefore important that all objects in the scene have appropriate material properties set.

You may be interested in this article that [mentions all the common mistakes](http://www.sjbaker.org/steve/omniv/opengl_lighting.html) one makes when trying to illuminate scenes.

[image]

You will want to look up the glColorMaterial functions as they are the easiest way to set material properties.

Answer (score 2):

Like Frank said, lights are invisible, they are merely used as an input to the lighting equation used by the rendering system (hardware/software) to calculate the final colors of geometry.

If you want something to look like a light you need to mimic the effects that you are used to seeing when looking at a bright light source. For the sun one of the most noticeable effects is light bloom.

For information on generating light bloom read this [OpenGL Bloom Tutorial](http://prideout.net/bloom/index.php), and here is some [sample code](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Advanced-Graphics/BloomOpenGL.htm) in Java using GLSL to generate a bloom effect.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on if you want full bloom style effects (if so, look at Josh Perry's answer) or just a not-dark object object that seems to emit light you might want to consider this simple approach.

- Render the scene without the actual 'sun' mesh but with a point light at the centre of your 'sun'.
- Disable GL Lighting.
- Render a sphere or use a [billboard](http://www.lighthouse3d.com/opengl/billboarding/) to render an image of your sun in the appropriate spot.
- Re-enable GL Lighting before you display your next frame.

Because you've disabled lighting, the sun will be rendered 'full-bright' with no shading or lighting calculations being performed.